# Can't retrieve metadata for Blob in azure storage blob with java

Tags: java, azure, blob

I am using java api for azure as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-java-stable

In the code sample below i am able to retrieve blob content from the BlobItem object with exception of "metadata" which returns null despite the fact that i have added metadata manually to the blob in azure portal.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new 
BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(azConnectionString).buildClient();
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("myContainer")

ListBlobsOptions listsBlobOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
listsBlobOptions.getDetails().getRetrieveMetadata();

blobContainerClient.listBlobs(listsBlobOptions, Duration.ofHours(1000)).forEach(blobItem -> {
    log.info(blobItem.getName());
    log.info(blobItem.getProperties().getETag());
    log.info(String.valueOf(blobItem.getProperties().getLeaseStatus()));
    log.info(String.valueOf(blobItem.getMetadata()));
  });
```

Help is appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason you're not getting the metadata is because you're not [`setting`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/com/azure/storage/blob/models/BlobListDetails.html#setRetrieveMetadata-boolean-) the metadata option.

Can you try something like the following (untested code):

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new 
BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(azConnectionString).buildClient();
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("myContainer")

BlobListDetails blobListDetails = (new BlobListDetails()).setRetrieveMetadata(true);//set "retrieve metadata" option to true
ListBlobOptions listBlobOptions = (new ListBlobOptions()).setDetails(blobListDetails);

blobContainerClient.listBlobs(listsBlobOptions, Duration.ofHours(1000)).forEach(blobItem -> {
    log.info(blobItem.getName());
    log.info(blobItem.getProperties().getETag());
    log.info(String.valueOf(blobItem.getProperties().getLeaseStatus()));
    log.info(String.valueOf(blobItem.getMetadata()));
  });
```

Comment: Setting the metadata option solved the issue :) Thank you!